# How to Add Seller Information into invoice pdf in magento without using extension

Tags: magento-1.9

For each product we have different seller so how to get that seller information on the invoice pdf and packing slip?

Comment: fyi: modules/extensions are used to change any Magento behavior that is not accessible through configurations.  If you need to change behavior without a module, then you are proposing a violation of the principle: Do not modify the core code. Your solution, as you asked requires changing the core code to suit your needs. Do this with caution.
    
Your best option is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/s4-customizable-pdf-invoice-template.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override two model class

```
1. Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
```

In this class you have to change in function `_drawHeader` and it should be something like

```
protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'),
            'feed' => 35
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Saller'),
            'feed' => 150
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'),
            'feed'  => 360,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
            'feed'  => 565,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 5
        );

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }
```

I have added one more column for seller after product name.

Now for the value of the seller you will need to override model class

```
2. Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default
```

In this class you will need to change in function `drow()` and it should be like

```
public function draw()
    {
        $order  = $this->getOrder();
        $item   = $this->getItem();
        $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
        $page   = $this->getPage();
        $lines  = array();

        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = array(array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 35, true, true),
            'feed' => 35,
        ));

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split('Seller', 35, true, true),
            'feed' => 150,
        );

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $item->getQty() * 1,
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 395;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 170;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData){
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = array(
                    'text'  => $priceData['label'],
                    'feed'  => $feedPrice,
                    'align' => 'right'
                );
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = array(
                    'text'  => $priceData['label'],
                    'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
                    'align' => 'right'
                );
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = array(
                'text'  => $priceData['price'],
                'feed'  => $feedPrice,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = array(
                'text'  => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'font'  => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = array(
                    'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35
                );

                if ($option['value']) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $_printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $_printValue = strip_tags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $_printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = array(
                            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 30, true, true),
                            'feed' => 40
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 20
        );

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $this->setPage($page);
    }
```

This will add new column for seller in pdf, you will need to get seller information from item object

```
$lines[0][] = array(
                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split('Seller', 35, true, true),
                'feed' => 150,
            );
```

Instead of `'Seller'` you can get seller info from `$item` object if you can get from it like `$item->getSeller()`.

Comment: Thank You for this , but i need the complete seller info to be displayed like Billing Or shipping address in that invoice pdf. Can you plz help me with that ?